# How to compare KeyValuePair in C#

Tags: c#

I have one Dictionary and one List.
In List there is KeyValuePair and there is KeyValuePair in Dictionary. Is it possible to compare it?

I want to get table of things where these elements are equal.
My idea was something like it:

```
Class Fist
{

public List<keyValuePair<string, string>> List;
}

Class Second
{
public Dictionary<int, keyValuePair<string,string>> Dictionary;
}
```

and :

```
First First;
Second Second;
```

then I add some values using methods which aren't important here.

finally I've tought about:

```
if((First.List.Keys && First.List.Values) == (Second.Dictionary.Keys && Second.Dictionary.Values)
```

but it doesn't work. Any help?

[EDIT]

My mistake, I forgot about most important thing.
I want to return this "int" element from Dictionary -thx for it  Tim Schmelter

Comment: oh, i've forgotten :/  I want to return this "int" element from Dictionary. But only if comparison is true

Comment: Please post a compilable sample of what you've got, and try describing more precisely what do you want. E.g. there is no such class as `keyValuePair`, no keyword `Class`, etc.

Comment: @Lorn: why don't you include such important informations in your question? You can edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets flesh out the code by actually creating the list and the dictionary in the object, and actually creating instances of the classes:

```
class First {
  public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> List =
    new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
}

class Second {
  public Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, string>> Dictionary =
    new Dictionary<int,KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
}

First first = new First();
Second second = new Second();
```

Let's add some items to the list and dictionary:

```
first.List.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("asdf", "1"));
first.List.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("qwerty", "2"));
first.List.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("poiuy", "3"));

second.Dictionary.Add(42, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("fdfdf", "x"));
second.Dictionary.Add(99, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("asdf", "1"));
second.Dictionary.Add(1337, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("qwerty", "nope"));
```

Now you can get the keys from the dictionary where there is an exact match for an item in the list:

```
int[] found = second.Dictionary
  .Where(d => first.List.Contains(d.Value))
  .Select(d => d.Key)
  .ToArray();
```

For the example data that would give you an array with one item, having the value `99`.

Answer (score 0):

To get keys from the dictionary that correspond to any element of the list you can try this:

```
var result = second
    .Dictionary
    .Where(kvp => first.List.Contains(kvp.Value))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

Demo:

```
Fist first = new Fist();
Second second = new Second();
first.List = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
first.List.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "y"));
first.List.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "w"));
second.Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
second.Dictionary.Add(0, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "y"));
second.Dictionary.Add(1, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "y"));
second.Dictionary.Add(2, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "z"));
second.Dictionary.Add(3, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "w"));

var result = second
    .Dictionary
    .Where(kvp => first.List.Contains(kvp.Value))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToArray();

foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Gives:

```
0
1
3
```

Comment: That checks if the dictionary contains all the items in the list, but it will give a false positive if the dictionary contains additional items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if all keys and all values in the list and the dictionary are equal:

```
var keysList = new HashSet<string>(first.List.Select(kv => kv.Key));
var valuesList = new HashSet<string>(first.List.Select(kv => kv.Value));
var keysDict = new HashSet<string>(second.Dictionary.Values.Select(kv => kv.Key));
var valuesDict = new HashSet<string>(second.Dictionary.Values.Select(kv => kv.Value));
bool sameKeys = valuesList.SetEquals(keysDict);
bool sameValues = keysList.SetEquals(valuesDict);
```

**Update** (according your comment) *"I want to return this "int" element from Dictionary. But only if comparison is true"*

```
var ints = from kvDict in second.Dictionary
           join kvList in first.List
           on new { kvDict.Value.Key, kvDict.Value.Value } equals new { kvList.Key, kvList.Value }
           select kvDict.Key;
```

Comment: The items in the dictionary doesn't have any specific order.

Comment: @Guffa: yes, meanwhile i'm using different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get a sequence of all the `Dictionary` `KeyValuePair`s that are also in the `List` then you can use the `Union` extension method:

```
var items = Dictionary.Values.Union(List);
```

Comment: All that are in both would be the intersection, not the union